# The Cramer-Rao Lower Bound proof

Tags: statistical-inference, proof-explanation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be i.i.d. with density function $f (x|θ)$. Let $T = t (X_1, . . . , X_n)$
be an unbiased estimate of $θ$. Then, under smoothness assumptions on $f (x|θ)$,
$$Var(T) >= \frac{1}{I(θ)}$$

Can you please help me(explaining step by step) with understanding the derivation o this inequality? Because i undertand the idea of this inequality but i am completely lost with derivation.

Also i want to know why do we write Let $T = t (X_1, . . . , X_n)$
be an unbiased estimate of $θ$ ?Because usually i have seen only one symbol, smth like $\bar x$ is the estimator of $θ$. Appearance of $T = t (X_1, . . . , X_n)$ is confusing for me.
And also in proof arises covariance and i don't understand why.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question regarding $T = t(X_1,..., X_n)$: this notation allows us to think of an estimator as any function of the data (and only the data). This is, in many cases, the mean; but writing it as a statistic permits any statistic of the data (e.g. the maximum of the data etc.).